# Node-red Unable to listen on http://127.0.0.1:1880

Tags: iot, node-red

When I try to start node-red by PUTTY with the cmd line:

```
node-red
```

I receive the following error and I can't open node-red by my browser:

> 9 Jan 14:13:05 - [error] Unable to listen on http://127.0.0.1:1880/
>   9 Jan 14:13:05 - [error] Error: port in use

I don't know how to fix this problem!
Thanks

Comment: This question is specifically about a programming tool.

Comment: @hardillb the same problem applies to everything that listens to incoming connections. If someone else has taken port 1880, then that port is taken, and that's not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

That error implies that something is already using port 1880, normally I would suggest this is another instance of Node-RED.

The fact that you can't connect to `http://127.0.0.1:1880` from your other machine (I'm guessing windows) is that 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, you need to change 127.0.0.1 for the ip address you gave to Putty in order to connect to the remote machine.

You've not said what platform you are on, but on Linux you can use the lsof command to show which process has what port open e.g.:

```
sudo lsof -i :1880
```

Comment: i've installed node-red on iot2000

Comment: I have no idea what a iot200, but I assume it's some embedded linux box. I've edited the answer to add more details

Comment: node-red already ran on putty ip

Comment: No. assuming that you connected with putty to 192.168.0.123 then you need to try `http://192.168.0.123:1880` in the browser